# Matplotlib with py2exe and tkFileDialog

Tags: python, matplotlib, py2exe

I have successfully created a py2exe executable that is a script that calls matplotlib and plots a file - simple script that call a file and plots it without gtk or other
everything works fine except that the 'save the figure' button does not work - it gets the import error that it cant find tkFileDialog
Ive tried importing the FileDialog in the py2exe setup.py as well as adding the package: FileDialog and other ideas from my web searches, nothing seems to make it work - any ideas of how to make it work?

here is the py2exe script

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib
import sys
#import Tkinter as tk
import FileDialog


setup(windows=['C:\plotlog.py'], 

      options={
               'py2exe': {
                          'packages' :  ['matplotlib', 'pytz'],
                          'dll_excludes': ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libglib-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libcairo-2.dll',
                                         'libpango-1.0-0.dll',
                                         'libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll',
                                         'libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll',
                                         'libglade-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libgmodule-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libgthread-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'QtGui4.dll', 'QtCore.dll',
                                         'QtCore4.dll'
                                        ],
                          }
                },
      data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),)
```

Comment: this is with  matplotlib 2.0.2 BTW

Comment: from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib
import sys
import FileDialog
setup(windows=['p.py'],
options={
'py2exe':{
'packages':['matplotlib', 'pytz'],
'dll_excludes':['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
'libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
'libglib-2.0-0.dll',
'libcairo-2.dll',
'libpango-1.0-0.dll',
'libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll',
'libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll',
'libglade-2.0-0.dll',
'libgmodule-2.0-0.dll',
'libgthread-2.0-0.dll',
'QtGui4.dll', 'QtCore.dll',
'QtCore4.dll'
],
}
},
data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),)